# Transparent Scrollbar that shows background

Tags: css, scrollbar

I'm trying to find a way to have a custom background for the scrollbar track while having the scrollbar itself (the "thumb") is transparent and you can see the background BEHIND the entire scrollbar.

I tried:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 15px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #f2d6ce; 
}::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: transparent;
}
```

However, the thumb becomes transparent and so you see the background of the track (#f2d6ce). Is there a way that I can make the thumb a sort of cutout of the scrollbar track to expose the background behind the whole scrollbar?
Thank you very much! :)